# What causes ModelBuilder error occurred in script on this page MdDlgContent.htm?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I've been creating a model in Arc 10.0 for a few days now without problems. Then I added the Calculate Field Tool. I selected Make Variable --> From Parameter --> Expression. When I check off "Model Parameter" on the expression variable once it's been added to the model, save and close the model, then try to open it in Toolbox, I receive two popup errors, both saying "An error has occurred in the script on this page."

The first error says Error: Expected ')' in Line 79 Character 70 (Code 0):
[image]

The second says The value of the property 'IntForm' is null or undefined, not a Function object in Line 465 Character 1 (Code 0):
[image]

Both messages are referencing the following URL: file:///C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.0/ArcToolbox/Dlg/MdDlgContent.htm.

I located [this article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38099) in ESRI support and followed the instructions, to no avail. (It must not be the exact same issue, as my message box doesn't reference Internet Explorer in the title). I also tried downloading SP5.

I opened the MdDlgContent.htm to take a look but that wasn't much help either because, despite some familiarity with Python and JavaScript, I am hardly a programmer.

Any help troubleshooting or resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!!

I posted this same question in the ESRI Forums as well:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/79448-Model-Builder-An-error-has-occurred-in-the-script-on-this-page.-MdDlgContent.htm

Comment: You may be encountering the problem described [**here**](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/13088-Running-tools-from-Search-window-gives-Webpage-Error-on-some-machines).  However, I've never seen it on a customised tool.  For OOTB tools the workaround I use is close ArcMap, re-open it and do exactly the same thing and all works until the next reboot.

Answer (score 2):

The issue strangely enough is caused by a dependency on Internet Explorer DLL dependencies of all strange things. It is triggered by opening the Item Description window - Try opening any tool, then opening the Item Description window for a tool, and then try re-opening that tool - the script error will occur.

A quick fix for this is to go into the Internet Explorer Internet settings (32 bit, not 64 bit version), going to Security, and then changing it from Medium-high to medium. This of course is the fastest way, and if you don't use Internet Explorer, there are no real security risks.

You can find a full writeup with a few more solutions here:
https://gisnuts.com/terra/blog/2013/01/22/arcgis-geoprocessing-tools-scripting-error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just repaired ArcGIS 10: insert the ArcGIS 10 DVD and select repair. It solved my problem.