# Getting Script Error has occurred in script on this page when running polygon to raster conversion?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

i keep getting the script error problem every time i try using polygon to raster tool in ArcGIS 10.1. Please help me how I can solve this?

screenshot embedded[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a problem that has [often plagued me](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/12726), although not for a while.

It has been discussed in a [Knowledge Base Technical Article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/33792) entitled:

> Problem:  On some systems, running any Geoprocessing tool in
>   ArcToolbox results in Microsoft Script Errors and the tool dialog box
>   appears blank

Two solutions/workarounds are offered there:

> - Uninstall the offending software, such as FireRMS or EDO.
> - Reregister the msxml3.dll file located in the C:\windows\system32 folder by doing the following:
>
>   1. Type CMD in the run window to bring up the command window.
>   2. Type regsvr32 C:\windows\system32\msxml3.dll and press Enter.

I cannot endorse or dismiss the advice above because the way I work around it is simply to close and restart ArcMap.  Invariably I can then open the same tool that a few minutes earlier would not open.

If all else fails then it should be noted that [the asker of this question commented that an uninstall/reinstall of ArcGIS for Desktop resolved this problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122952/getting-script-error-has-occurred-in-script-on-this-page-when-running-polygon-to/122954#comment176673_122954) but I have never needed to do that to resolve this.

One user here has seen the same error come from ModelBuilder in [What causes ModelBuilder error occurred in script on this page MdDlgContent.htm?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53928/what-causes-modelbuilder-error-occurred-in-script-on-this-page-mddlgcontent-htm) but I have not seen it come from ModelBuilder.